# Safest method to integrate web version of Email

Tags: php, security, email, uuid

I am having a couple of mails in which I need to implement web versions. But I don't want to pass sensitive information like UUID or userID. I have a "View in browser" link and when user clicks on it, it should take the user to the website page, which will take input from GET and display specific content for each of the user. How this can be implemented ?

I am already using UUID here and passing it through the URL, which will turn fetch the user from DB and display the contents. It is a fool proof method ?

I am doing this in PHP

Answer (score 0):

If it's super-sensitive information, put it behind your sites login mechanism.

If it's just something random people should not stumble upon by accident, just generate a random unique ID (like you do) which you associate with the e-mail and display the user data. Again, this should probably not give any third-party a possibility to change or impersonate the user, just read the e-mail of one e-mail.